# Android volley, onresponse order different from sent order

Tags: android, android-volley

Hopefully someone is able to help me, I've searched for sometime but with no luck.

I'm using volley for network calls, I sort data server side and  receive response clientside as JsonObject.

All is well with my note 4, data received in the same order as it was sent, however on tab 4 order is different...

E.g.

```
Note 4
Android 6.0.1
Response {'1':'a','2':'b','3':'c'} etc...

Tab 4
Android 4.4.2
Response {'2':'b','1':'a','3':'c'} etc..
```

I tested my app on other devices running 6.0.1 without issues. Has anyone else encountered this issue with Android 4.4.2?

Answer (score 0):

JSON object is unordered collection, so the order can be random. You could use a list of pairs, if you need to get ordered data:

```
[
  ['a', '1'],
  ['b', '2'],
]
```

Comment: I am echoing json_encode, should i not receive in the same order? as I have never had any problems till testing on a tab 4 running 4.4.2.

Comment: If you echo the string, then yes, you should expect the same order. But if you go through serialization-deserialization (like JSONObject->String->JSONObject) process anywhere in the call chain, the order can change every time you process the data.

Comment: Response is unmodified, I'm logging initial response as "response.toString()".

Comment: I presume that response is a Java object that was deserialized from JSON. In such case this is an unordered map and you can't rely on the order of elements.

Comment: Thanks for your information, Best practice would be to sort json response client side then right?